# Probability of pulling discs (python)

Tags: python, geometry, probability

using python 3.3 , I am supposed to answer the following questions:

From a box full of discs, we would like to know the probability of pulling two blue discs
in a row when all the discs in the box are either red or blue. Write a function which can
calculate this probability for a box ﬁlled with any number of red discs and any number of
blue discs. A test case you may want to use: if the box contains 15 blue discs and 6 red
discs, you have a 50% chance of drawing two blue discs in a row.

Now write a function that calculates the probability of drawing n blue discs in a row for
some n between 0 and the number of discs in the box.

i have tried using this model

```
import random
def random_pick(some_list, probabilities):
    x = random.uniform(0, 1)
    cumulative_probability = 50.0
    for item, item_probability in zip(some_list, probabilities):
        cumulative_probability += item_probability
        if x < cumulative_probability: break
    return item
```

i am almost completely lost. Please help.

Comment: There are three ways of solving this. The first is a [Monte Carlo simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) where you try a large number of random values and count up the results. The second is to actually calculate the probabilities through math analysis. The third is to enumerate all the possible outcomes.

Comment: As Mark points out, there are a number of ways to solve this that you should be aware of. I provided the answer to the most straightforward for a problem like this, but I upvoted Mark because I think knowing the other statistical methods by which you could reach a solution is important.

Comment: @Mark, Monte Carlo doesn't really solve it, but can provide a useful approximation

Comment: You can also calculate the probabilities via dynamic programming, which can be useful if the math analysis is very difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`P(blue) = P(blue 1) * P(blue 2) * ... * P(blue n)`
If there are 15 blue discs and 6 red, there are 21 in total. The `P(blue 1)` is 15/21 = .7143. There are now 20 discs left, 14 of which are blue. Thus, `P(blue 2)` is 14/20 = 0.7. `0.7143 * 0.7 = 0.5`

You can repeat this for however many you need to pull.

In pseudo code:

```
probabilityOfBlue (numBlueInDeck, numRedInDeck, numBlueToPull)
  if (numBlueToPull > numBlueInDeck or numBlueToPull < 0 or (numBlueInDeck + numRedInDeck) == 0)
    return 0

  probability = 1.0
  i = 0
  while i < numBlueToPull
    probability = probability * (numBlueInDeck/(numBlueInDeck + numRedInDeck))
    numBlueInDeck = numBlueInDeck - 1
    i = i + 1

  return probability
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have trouble implementing that information into function format. Can you help me?

Comment: pseudocode added using an iterative solution. Since it's homework, I leave it up to you to implement the actual code :)

Comment: thank you, What part of the function does 15 and 6 go to? and also, does this function apply to the first or second question i asked?

Comment: As per my comment above to perreal's recursive solution, this solution addresses any case. the I'd think it obvious, but 15 and 6 go to numBlueInDeck and numRedInDeck, respectively.

Comment: i tried implementing the function but i keep getting a syntax error in the first line - def probabilityOfBlue(15, 6, 2):   (15 is highlighted in the syntax error). what is wrong?

Comment: @AkumaUkpo: Python expects a *name* here: `def probabilityOfBlue(blue, red, n):` You might find [resources for non-programmers useful](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers)

Comment: Akuma: this isn't a programmed answer, and I don't know if it's valid python (though from what I've seen of the language, it's probably quite close :D).  It's pseudocode, which means it describes algorithmically what your code should do in order to implement this solution. I left it intentionally spaced out, without "syntactic sugar" or concepts that are more difficult for some people to understand during their initial approach into coding.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of drawing a single blue disc is equal to the ratio of blue discs to total discs, e.g., if you have 2 blue discs and 2 red discs you have 0.5 change of drawing a blue one.

If you want to draw a second disc, since you already removed one blue, you need to calculate the probability with one less (blue) disc. So you have 1 blue 2 red discs now and hence 1/3 prob. Since this probability depends on the first condition, you need to multiply two probabilities, i.e., 1/2 * 1/3.

In general:

```
def prob_blue_inrow(numb, numr, n): 
  p = numb / (numr + numb * 1.0)
  if (n == 1): 
    return p
  else:
    return p *  prob_blue_inrow(numb - 1, numr, n - 1)

print(prob_blue_inrow(15, 6, 2))
```

Comment: thank you :) is this function for the first or second question?

Comment: this is the second one, if you pass 2 for `n` then it is the first one also

Comment: It's an answer for both. For the first one, n = 2. It's a recursive solution, which may cause problems if numb, numr, and n are too large (stack overflow). However, it's tail recursive, so the frame context can be discarded and it would likely work in a non-debug build for practically any value of n.

Comment: @AkumaUkpo maybe try to understand the code instead of just pasting it  as your own for your homework.

Comment: Please follow ecline6's advice and understand what's going on here. You get no benefit from this if you copy an answer without understanding how or why it works. Of course, there's a flaw or two in perreal's solution, so it's especially important to know what it's trying to do ;)

Comment: @ecline6 that is what i am trying to do : understand the code. i have looked at a lot of textbooks but to no avail. so i came here hoping a coder could explain a little to me. I didn't even know where to start when i attempted to solve this problem. This is my first time ever programming, and things are coming in really slowly for me :(  and this isn't homework, it is a practice problem meant to help me become familiar with probability functions in python.

Comment: @Tawnos also, is there anyway i could test this function? i am not too good with writing assert statements.

Comment: @AkumaUkpo  Things like knowing how to write a function and calling it are not questions for stackoverflow.  Answers to those questions are explored in great detail in any of the many Python tutorials out on the web.  Go to learnpythonthehardway.org  and spend a month with it.

Comment: @AkumaUkpo, just paste this into a file named `script.py` and run `python script.py`

Comment: +1: concise. It handles `numb < n` case in a subtle manner and doesn't handle `numb + numr == 0` at all. You could [use `fractions.Fraction` to get the precise result](http://ideone.com/RsDVHC). Also `/` is a float division in Python 3, and `print` is a function, not a statement.

Comment: Akuma: for testing, you need to try various cases that can make the code fail as well as verify it succeeds. Try a base case (the one you know works). Try some edge cases (where one thing appears to be wrong, e.g. something that might cause a divide by zero, or might cause the program to never end), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Enumeration of all the cases is not too CPU intensive for this case

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> sum('r' not in x for x in combinations('b' * 15 + 'r' * 6, 2))
105
>>> sum(1 for x in combinations('b'*15+'r'*6, 2))
210
>>> 105/210.0
0.5
```

Even 1000 blue and 1000 red can be enumerated in much less than a second. It performs very badly if you increase the number of samples to say 3 though :)

Comment: how can this be written as a function?

Comment: @AkumaUkpo I'm trying to be polite here, but stackoverflow is not really the forum to ask basic syntax questions.  My humble opinion is that the problem you're giving yourself to solve is a little bit too hard yet.  I can recommend www.learnpythonthehardway.org as an excellent tutorial on the basics.